# Git only checks in top level

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am just getting started with Git.  I want to take a project that I have created and upload it into BitBucket.  The file structure is nested, as a normal software project can be.  The problem is that I only get the top level of files/folders commited.  DO I have to go through each folder in my solution/project and manually check them in?  Here is what I am doing:

```
$ git init
$ git add . #Isn't this supposed to iterate through the nested fodders?
$ git commit - m "some comment here..."
$ git push -u origin master
```

I would have hoped that this would check in all files in my solution, but it only checks in the first nested level of folders.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Git should traverse down your folder structure. However, it will ignore empty folders. Could that be it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `git add -A` instead of `git add .` This will add all of the things.

From the man page:

```
-A, --all
           Like -u, but match <filepattern> against files in the working tree in
           addition to the index. That means that it will find new files as well
           as staging modified content and removing files that are no longer in
           the working tree.
```

Pro tip:

I have `aa` aliased to `git add -A && git status -s`. This is almost always what I want to do according to my workflow (add all my changes please), and then shows me the status so that I'm ready to make a commit. `aa` because it's super easy to type.

In bash:

```
aa='git add -A && git status -s'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `git add *`  and `git add directory` to add the directory and all the files recursively.